# ElementaryOS 0.3.2 AMD64; Macbook Air 2008: Wifi after installing

Tags: networking

I have the same problems that several people had before.
Wifi ain't working.

However, installing the libnl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 and libnl-genl-3-200 did not work, nor did downgrading.

At first it worked, however, after a reboot it stopped working again (not after the one immediately after the reinstallation but after the weekend ...) 
So I tried to fix it again, downgrading etc. Installing the libnl-* files did neither work using apt-get nor work by doing so manually.
After hours of doing so I got frustrated and reinstalled elementaryOS for the first time. Again non aforementioned ways of fixing WiFi worked... after another hour of trying all fixes I could think of I'm now in the process of reinstalling it again (first time with active Ethernet ... )

Can anyone point out another way of fixing the WiFi

If you need any information to help me, please say so and I will do my best to deliver that info.

Comment: Here! Take a look https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the b43 firmware drivers.

Open terminal and check your Wireless card model

`lshw -C network`

For models:
 * BCM4306/3;
 * BCM4311;
 * BCM4318;
 * BCM4321;
 * BCM4322 (only 14e4:432b);
 * BCM4312 (with Low-Power a.k.a. LP-PHY).

Install with `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`

For models:
 * BCM4301;
 * BCM4306/2;
 * BCM4306.

Install with `sudo apt install firmware-b43legacy-installer`

Comment: The BCMx number does not really matter apparently. If you do `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4`, you should pay attention to the number behind 14e4. For example: BCM4321 has 2 drivers. 4328 has b43 and 4329 has bcmwl-kernel-source. The following webpage also has a nice table of support: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/