# Can't connect to internet with my old MacBook Air running Elementary OS

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, macbook, internet

I've installed the Elementary OS onto my old MacBook Air. I can't get the laptop to recognize and connect to my wifi though. Any suggestions?

Pix... 934 shows that I don't have a regular LAN connection.

Pix...754 shows that none of my Wi-Fi connections are showing up.

Pix... 624 is the new screen that shows up when I select one of my WiFi connections.

Pix... 604 shows all the available Wi-Fi connections.

Pix... 414 shows the screen when I turn the computer on and press & hold the 'Options' button after the computer makes the little music sound.

[image: Pix... 934 shows that I don't have a regular LAN connection.]

[image: Pix...754 shows that none of my Wi-Fi connections are showing up.]

[[image: Pix... 624 is the new screen that shows up when I select one of my WiFi connections. [3]]

[image: Pix... 604 shows all the available Wi-Fi connections.]

[image: Pix... 414 shows the screen when I turn the computer on and press & hold the 'Options' button after the computer makes the little music sound.]

I read something somewhere about needing to activate the network or something. Any thoughts?

I was hopeful when I saw this 'Options' screen with my WiFi connections. So I tried all of them and still nothing. I think I'm missing something real simple here. Humm...

Appreciate all & any help. Dan

---

Okay, so I got into the GRUB menu by pressing the 'esc' key within the press hold the 'option' key after you hear the Macbook chime at startup. Here are the lists of items to choose from after typing 'help' at the GRUB menu screen came up. Any suggestions?[image: GRUB menu list 1][image: GRUB menu list 2]

Comment: Hey Dan! What model year (about) is the machine and can you run 'lspci' in a terminal and tell us what it shows for the Network Controller?

Comment: Mac OS X, 1.6 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, Memory:

Comment: I'm stepping out for a while but have a look at this post and see if gets you rolling in the right direction: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/elementaryos-0-3-2-amd64-macbook-air-2008-wifi-after-installing

Comment: THANKS! I'll be out for a few hours too. MacBookAir1,1. Mac OS X, Processor: 1.6 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, Memory: 2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM, It has a date of 2009 Apple, inc. Bus Speed: 800 MHz. As for the lspci here are the results: SMB: Intel 8201H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03) Broadband BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 05) There's lot's of other things but they are all in the same family 8201H (ICH8 Family). Thanks!

Comment: I think what you'll be looking for is in the link in my previous comment. Your wireless device is the BCM4321, if you didn't already know... Good Luck!!!

Comment: Okay linux_tim so I've got that update but my wifi icon still is grayed out and doesn't show my 4 possible wifi connections...anymore ideas for me to try?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73513/discussion-between-linux-tim-and-dan-tisdale).

Comment: Have you tried connecting via LAN (by cable) and installed the proprietary Broadcom wireless driver for the network card? Because as I recall, some distributions will tell you that there are no connections, when in truth the hardware is just not configured at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to open directly in the boot process with the esc button Grub. A menu appears to confirm extended processes for eOS and start with the Rev. item. In the menu a sub-item Activate network appears. Run Rev. completely and restart and your network should be activated

Comment: Please translate your answer to English. You can use machine translation if you prefer; others can improve it afterwards if there's need for clarification.

Comment: Thanks user13814 for your suggestion. I'll give it a try. Here's Google's translation BTW. Hello try to open directly in the boot process with the esc button Grub. A menu appears to confirm extended processes for eOS and start with the Rev. item. In the menu a sub-item Activate network appears. Run Rev. completely and restart and your network should be activated.